# Search for external content source using sharepoint 2010

Tags: enterprise-search

I have set up an external content source, crawled the data and set up a search scope which is successfully returning results from the external source.

How can that external content source (website) make use of the same search functionality to display a search box and results on its own pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can write either javascript or other code to call the SharePoint Search Query Web Service and post a query and return results. If you move to SharePoint 2013 you can use REST for the request/response.

Once you get the results back it is up to you to build the result user interface. There are tons of examples if you search for them.